# Jersey and @FormParam not working when charset is specified in the Content-Type

Tags: java, servlets, http-headers, jersey, jax-rs

It seems like Jersey 2.0 (using servlet 3.1) is not able to decode a parameter when the `charset` property is specified in the `Content-Type` header.

For example considering the following endpoint:

```
@POST
@Path("/hello")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response hello(@FormParam("name") String name) {
    System.out.println(name);
    return ok();
}
```

This curl request works:

```
curl -X POST -H "content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -d "name=tom" http://localhost:8080/sampleapp/hello
```

The following request instead **doesn't** work and the `name` parameter is `null`:

```
curl -X POST -H "content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8" -d "name=tom" http://localhost:8080/sampleapp/hello
```

I think the `charset=UTF-8` addition in the content type breaks my code.

**EDIT:**

I've opened an official ticket just in case this is a bug: https://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY-1978

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think it's a bug.

There's a pull request open to support this use case:
https://github.com/jersey/jersey/pull/24/files

In the meantime I'd suggest to use a filter to remove the offending encoding.

**EDIT** as per OP comments

I'm thinking on something along these lines:

```
@Provider
@PreMatching
public class ContentTypeFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter{

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext)
            throws IOException {
        MultivaluedMap<String,String> headers=requestContext.getHeaders();
        List<String> contentTypes=headers.remove(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE);
        if (contentTypes!=null && !contentTypes.isEmpty()){
            String contentType= contentTypes.get(0);
            String sanitizedContentType=contentType.replaceFirst(";.*", "");
            headers.add(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, sanitizedContentType);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How can I use a filter to modify the `Content-Type` header?

Comment: I modified the answer. It's untested, though.

Comment: Solved in Jersey v2.22

Answer (score 4):

Here is a simple work-around inspired by Carlo's post. The only modification is to match '; charset=UTF-8'; otherwise, 'multipart/form-data; boundary=...' content types fail.

```
// IMPLEMENTATION NOTE: Resolves an issue with FormParam processing
// @see https://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY-1978

@Provider
@PreMatching
public class ContentTypeFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {
        MultivaluedMap<String,String> headers = requestContext.getHeaders();
        List<String> contentTypes = headers.remove(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE);
        if (contentTypes != null && !contentTypes.isEmpty()) {
            String contentType = contentTypes.get(0);
            String sanitizedContentType = contentType.replaceFirst("; charset=UTF-8", "");
            headers.add(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, sanitizedContentType);
        }
    }
}
```