# null in FormParam with "charset=UTF-8" in Jersey 2.0

Tags: post, jersey-2.0

I'm currently working on an AngularJS project and I'm calling some rest services using content-type "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;".

On server side I use Jersey in version 2.0. This is my maven dependency.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Everthing work fine on Chrome and IE7. My problem is Firefox who add mystically "charset=UTF-8" in the content type.

I made some test and if I use POSTMAN and set "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8" in the content type, Jersey has null in all FormParam parameters

This is the header of my method in java

```
@POST
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("movements/")
public Response movements(
        @FormParam("COMPTE_NO") String COMPTE_NO,
        @FormParam("COMPTE_BIDULE") String COMPTE_BIDULE,
        @FormParam("COMPTE_MACHIN") String COMPTE_MACHIN,
```

I tried with this headers

```
@POST
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("movements/")
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED + ";charset=UTF-8", 
           MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED + "; charset=UTF-8",
           MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED})
public Response movements(
        @FormParam("COMPTE_NO") String COMPTE_NO,
        @FormParam("COMPTE_BIDULE") String COMPTE_BIDULE,
        @FormParam("COMPTE_MACHIN") String COMPTE_MACHIN,
```

And I had exactly the same problem. Do you have an idea ? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is a duplication. A response can be found on [Jersey and @FormParam not working when charset is specified in the Content-Type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17602432/jersey-and-formparam-not-working-when-charset-is-specified-in-the-content-type)

Jersey ticket and filter has a workaround can be found on the ticket