# How do I sneak my message body past Jersey, perhaps using Mule

Tags: java, post, jersey, mule, form-parameter

So I'm using an older version of Mule (*3.3.1*) and Jersey (*1.6*) -very new to both and unable to upgrade- and having a similar problem to ["null in FormParam with “charset=UTF-8” in Jersey 2.0"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17972878/null-in-formparam-with-charset-utf-8-in-jersey-2-0) in that HTML form data being `@POST`ed is always `null` but using [curl](/questions/tagged/curl) (to force a non UTF-8 charset) makes no difference, my `@FormParam`s are still `null`.

```
<flow name="repo" doc:name="Repository application">
    <inbound-endpoint ref="RepositoryInternalEndpoint">
        <not-filter>
            <wildcard-filter pattern="/favicon.ico"/>
        </not-filter>
    </inbound-endpoint>

    <!-- All seems fine at this point -->
    <!--<custom-interceptor class="TestInterceptor"/>-->

    <!-- Inside the RepositoryService class, @FormParam args are null -->
    <jersey:resources doc:name="Repository Service Component">
        <component>
            <spring-object bean="repositoryService"/>
        </component>
    </jersey:resources>
</flow>
```

It seems as though Jersey is just eating my request body.  Given that if I insert the `TestInterceptor` (in comments above) which simply outputs message properties including the message body and `@FromParam`s, all the expected data is there. Is there a way to stop Jersey doing this or get the data beforehand?

The expected `@FormParam` arguments are all `String` as such...

```
@POST
@Path("/my/url")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
public Response myMethod(@FormParam("o_serviceId") String serviceId){}
```

The [curl](/questions/tagged/curl) command used was

```
curl -X POST -H "content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -d "o_serviceId=12345y" localhost:8889/my/url
```

Comment: What is the expected `Content-Type` of the method annotated with `@FormParam`? What `curl` command did you use?

Comment: Both added to the question.

Comment: Thanks. Everything looks fine so it seems like a bug. Could you potentially deploy you app on a more recent Mule just to see if it's an issue that's been fixed?

Comment: I'm afraid not.  It's a very messy, very huge legacy app with untold pain on library updates.  I'd have liked to find a workaround but if there's nothing I think the easiest option is just not to use [tag:Jersey] and try do what I'm trying to do with something I can control a bit better like [tag:Spring].

Comment: Ah that's too bad, sorry to read this. Is there a transformer configured in `RepositoryInternalEndpoint`? Maybe things get screwed up there?

Comment: It's a `jetty:endpoint` with `connector-ref` set to a `NullSessionHandler`.  That doesn't matter though right?  The request body still exists in the flow after that endpoint.

Comment: I can reproduce the problem. If I switch to an `http:endpoint` instead of a `jersey:` one things work fine. Could you use such an endpoint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are getting bitten by this long standing issue: https://www.mulesoft.org/jira/browse/MULE-5687

When comparing Mule message payloads between the HTTP and the Jetty connectors, I noticed that it's actually an empty String for `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` requests for the latter while it contains the actual body for the former.

Indeed if I add this before `jersey:resources`, everything works fine:

```
<set-payload
    value="#[org.mule.util.StringUtils.join(message.inboundProperties['request.parameters'].entrySet(),'&amp;')]" />
```

This basically rebuilds the message payload out of the request parameters. It's a quick and dirty fix: it does not re-encode the parameters properly and it assumes that `Map.Entry.toString()` always returns `key=value`. But it's easy to improve with a proper `Map to URL-encoded string` transformation...

Comment: This sounds about right, I'll give this a try later in the week.

Comment: It works. Excellent, thanks.  Wouldn't have though of moving it to params.