# Use of charter encoding with content type in JAX-RS 2.0 - Jersey

Tags: rest, jersey, jax-rs

I am developing JAX-RS 2.0 client with Jersey implementation. REST API returns response with content type as 'application/json; UTF-8'

At client side, Jersey cannot recognize this content-type and throws error like

**Unable to parse "Content-Type" header value: "application/json; UTF-8"**

```
 org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.HeaderValueException: Unable to parse "Content-Type" header value: "application/json; UTF-8"
at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.InboundMessageContext.exception(InboundMessageContext.java:318)
at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.InboundMessageContext.singleHeader(InboundMessageContext.java:313)
at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.InboundMessageContext.getMediaType(InboundMessageContext.java:427)
```

If content type is **"application/json**" same code could process the response. I tried to search over google and some posts say that such character encoding along with content type is supported in Jersey but I didn't find it working.

Following is code I am trying with.

```
Client clientSaml = ClientBuilder.newBuilder().sslContext(context)
            .hostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
                @Override
                public boolean verify(String arg0, SSLSession arg1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method`enter code here` stub
                    return true;
                }
            }).build();

    clientSaml.register(new SAMLAuthenticator(token));
    clientSaml.register(new LoggingFilter());

    WebTarget target = clientSaml
            .target(URL_OF_API);

    Response resp = target.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).get();

    System.out.println(resp.getMediaType().toString());
```

Does anybody had this issue before and what could be possible solution of this ?? Does any other implementation of JAX-RS support it ?

Comment: You might need to upgrade your Jersey version. According to the bug tracker, this problems was fixed in Jersey 2.2 (https://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY-1978). There is also a link to a workaround in there.

Comment: I am using Jersey 2.11. I doubt this was fixed in 2.2 because from Jira defect log it shows this was closed as 'cannot reproduce'. I instead now try workaround mentioned at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17602432/jersey-and-formparam-not-working-when-charset-is-specified-in-the-content-type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did workaround of this issue using ClientResponseFilter

Thanks to hint suggested in [Jersey and @FormParam not working when charset is specified in the Content-Type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17602432/jersey-and-formparam-not-working-when-charset-is-specified-in-the-content-type)

Answer (score 1):

You forgot `charset=`:

```
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
```

See [Section 14.17 Content-Type of HTTP 1.1](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html).