# Android HttpPost to Jersey web service returns 404

Tags: java, android, jersey, http-post, jax-rs

I am trying to post a resource within my android app. `GET` works without any problems. `POST` on the other sides returns a 404 when executing `response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()` in the end of my android snippet (see below)

My Jersey web service method looks like this:

```
@POST
@Path("/create")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON + ";charset=utf-8")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
public Response create(@FormParam("name") String name,
        @FormParam("description") String description) throws IOException {

    User user = new User();
    user.setName(name);
    user.setDescription(description);
    // store object in database...
    return Response.status(Status.OK).build();
}
```

And the code in the android app:

```
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("**my-url**/create");
ArrayList<NameValuePair> paramspost = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
paramspost.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", "My name"));
paramspost.add(new BasicNameValuePair("description", "My description"));
    try {
        httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type",
            "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8");

        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(paramspost, "UTF-8"));
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

The status code is 404 in the end and nothing is stored in my database. What's wrong with my code?

Comment: have you tried restarting your webservice?

Comment: Uhm, wait. Where do you actually define "POST" as the HTML request method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that my changes didn't deploy correctly to `Tomcat`. I deletet everything from my `Tomcat` folder and deployed again (It looks like creating a war via eclipse doesn't always undeploy correctly).

This means that the code presented in my questions works fine like this. And I found out that removing the specifed content-type doesn't make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, you did never define a request method.

```
httpPost.setRequestMethod("POST");
```

This should solve your problem.

Comment: The method setRequestMethod(String) is undefined for the type HttpPost. I'm trying to do the same as here: http://www.androidsnippets.com/executing-a-http-post-request-with-httpclient

Comment: oh wait this is not an `HttpConnection` maybe you try it with this?

Answer (score 0):

In your request you're specifying Content-Type: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8", however in your resource you consume "MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED", which is I beleive without the charset extension. This may cause troubles, so there is no resource found, which can consume your request. Try to omit the charset property from the request header.

Also there is an issue with jersey and charset property in Content-Type. Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17602432/jersey-and-formparam-not-working-when-charset-is-specified-in-the-content-type)