# Calling a @POST from Jersey

Tags: java, web-services, rest, post, jersey

I was able to get a @GET request working on jersey and the relevant code is as follows

The code for the server

```
@Path("/Text")
@GET
public String Hello() {
    System.out.println("Text Being print");
    return "Abc";
}

@POST
@Path("/post/{name}/{gender}")
public Response createDataInJSON(@PathParam("name") String data, @PathParam("gender") String data2) {
    System.out.println("Post Method 1");

    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
    obj.put("Name", data);
    obj.put("Gender", data2);

    return Response
            .status(200)
            .entity(obj.toJSONString())
            .build();

}
```

The @POST also works when the parameters are passed in the url. (as mentioned in the above code segment)
But, it doesn't work when the parameters are not sent via the url. Like the code which follows.

```
@POST
@Path("/post2")
public Response createDataInJSON2(@FormParam("action") String data) {
    System.out.println("Post Method 2 : Data received:" + data);

    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
    obj.put("data", data);

    return Response
            .status(200)
            .entity(obj.toJSONString())
            .build();

}
```

May be the problem lies with the way the services are called.

```
//GET call (Plain Text)
    System.out.println(service.path("Hello").accept(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN).get(String.class));

    //POST call (Param)
    ClientResponse response = service.path("Hello/post/Dave/Male").post(ClientResponse.class);
    System.out.println(response.getEntity(String.class));

    //POST call (JSON)
    String input = "hello";

    ClientResponse response2 = service.path("Hello/post2").post(ClientResponse.class, input);
    System.out.println(response2.getEntity(String.class));
```

Can anyone tell me what am I missing here?

Comment: Can you clarify your question a bit? Which request doesn't work in particular?

Comment: @lunactic The second post method (which doesn't specify the parameters  in the url)

Answer (score 1):

Try to add a @Consumes (application/x-www-form-urlencoded) on your @POST method `createDataInJSON2` and explicitly add the same mime type in your request `service.path("Hello/post2").type(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED).post(ClientResponse.class, input)`.

Also consider that your input is just a simple string. Have a look at the class `MultivaluedMap`

If you have troubles with the Encoding then have a look at this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/18005711/3183976

Answer (score 0):

Try this. This worked for me.

The post method:

```
@POST
@Path("/post2")
public Response post2(String data) {
    System.out.println("Post method with File: " + data);

    return Response
            .status(200)
            .entity(data)
            .build();
}
```

The calling method:

```
ClientResponse response2 =service.path("Hello/post2").post(ClientResponse.class,"some value");
System.out.println(response2.getEntity(String.class));
```

Hope this helps. Peace.